# Simplifying binomial sums

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

What would be the easiest way to see (or show) that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left( (i \sqrt{3})^k-(-i \sqrt{3})^k\right) = i 2^{n+1} \sin \left({\frac{\pi n}{3}} \right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{n-k} \left( (i \sqrt{3})^k-(-i \sqrt{3})^k\right) = i 2^{n+1} \sin \left({\frac{\pi n}{3}} \right) ?
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$$

Comment: I can show that the first binomial sum is equal to $\left( 1+i\sqrt{3} \right)^n - \left(1-i \sqrt{3} \right)^n$ using Newton's binomial theorem, but I can't quite see an easy way to reduce this expression to the required one...

Comment: Then the second one is obtained with the same idea

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$ (i\sqrt{3})^k−(−i\sqrt{3})^k = 3^{k/2} (i^k-(-i)^k)$$

What happens to the expression when $k$ is even?